# Base64: How can i convert a URL to base64 format?

Tags: javascript, base64

i do have question, i have a PDF file fetched in my server which returns a resource location URL, I want to convert it to base64 how do i do that? thank you

Comment: You want to convert what to base 64?  The PDF??  Or the URL?  I don't exactly understand your question.

Comment: the PDF sir cullob

Comment: Which language are you planning to use? Do you have the path stored in the database or just in the filesystem?

Comment: the path is from aws server for example "location: www.aws.com/pdf.file" and i want to do it inside angularjs controller

Comment: `fetch(url).then(response => {return response.blob()}).then(blob => {let f = new FileReader(); f.onload = doSomethingWithDataURL; f.readAsDataURL(blob);});` `function doSomethingWithDataURL(evt){let dataURL = evt.target.result; ...}` or you could use xhr + `responseType = 'blob';` for ES5 browsers. Oh and you'll have to configure your aws so that it accepts cross-origin requests from your domain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you encode a string to Base64 in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246801/how-can-you-encode-a-string-to-base64-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this can help you

```
btoa('www.aws.com/pdf.file') //"d3d3LmF3cy5jb20vcGRmLmZpbGU="
```

Comment: i have other question why other URI starts with "data:application/pdf;base64"?